# Add a null value to a Varchar Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns with "name" and "surname" I want to return a result with the two concatenated.

but I have a problem, the surname column accept null values and when it's the case the concatenation is null.. I would like in this case just to have the NAME

here is code:

```
SELECT 
    c.ID_CONT,
    c.ID_TYPE_CONTACT,
    c.ID_PARAM_CENTRE,
    c.FONCTION_CONT,
    c.MEMO_CONT,
    c.VISIBLE_CONT,
    c.NAME_CONT +' '+c.SURNAME_CONT as NAMESURNAME      
FROM dbo.CONTACT c
```

It's works when Surname is blank or fulled..

Tx a lot..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
isnull(c.NAME_CONT +' ', '')+isnull(c.SURNAME_CONT,'')
```

Comment: Great answer but it begs the question why in Sql null + string = null?

Comment: @Marin because `NULL` is something unknown; how much money will you have if you got `unknown` plus `3 bucks`? Exactly `unknown` amount.

Answer (score 3):

Consider omitting the space separating character when `SURNAME_CONT` is the NULL value. Also consider handling when `SURNAME_CONT` is the empty string. `COALESCE` is Standard SQL e.g.

```
c.NAME_CONT + COALESCE(' ' + NULLIF(c.SURNAME_CONT, ''), '')
```

Answer (score 2):

there's a function ISNULL(expression, replacement_value)

[refer to msdn manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

so you could do:

```
SELECT 
    c.ID_CONT,
    c.ID_TYPE_CONTACT,
    c.ID_PARAM_CENTRE,
    c.FONCTION_CONT,
    c.MEMO_CONT,
    c.VISIBLE_CONT,
    c.NAME_CONT +' '+ISNULL(c.SURNAME_CONT, '') as NAMESURNAME      
FROM dbo.CONTACT c
```

Comment: If SURNAME_CONT is NULL, then you get NAME_CONT and a space. Do you want to have this trailing space there?

Comment: Not really important to have this Space ending the string, he is used to bind a dropdownlist.